# Convert Rows to Columns based on contents? (PIVOT?)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a report using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012.
I've got a fair amount of experience writing SQL reports, but have never had to use what I think should be a PIVOT until now.

Our RMM - Kaseya, uses the same column for all "custom audit fields", we have made a few custom "columns" like: SMART Drive Model, SMART Status, and SMART Last Updated date. You'd think these are defined as their own columns, but no -- regular entries in a cell, linked to an agentguid.

From looking at the table below, the fieldValue on the right is dependent on the fieldName to the left of it. I'm not sure how to turn these rows into their own columns based on the fieldName.

I'm seeking a query that produces five columns:

1. agentguid
2. Model
3. Size
4. Updated
5. Status

I will later run an INNER JOIN on this data, to compare against the agentguid and be able to customize my final report.

Below is a sample of data

```
SELECT * FROM vSystemInfoManual;
```

| Machine_GroupID | agentGuid | fieldName | fieldValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COMPUTER1.companyB | 101159575290188 | SMART Drive Model | PLEXTOR PX-256M5Pro ATA Device |
| COMPUTER1.companyB | 101159575290188 | Bitlocker Status | Off |
| COMPUTER1.companyB | 101159575290188 | SMART Drive Size | 238GB |
| COMPUTER1.companyB | 101159575290188 | SMART Updated | 01/14/2021 |
| COMPUTER1.companyB | 101159575290188 | SMART Status | CAUTION |
| COMPUTER2.companyA | 110275323879092 | SMART Drive Model | ST500DM002-1BD142 |
| COMPUTER2.companyA | 110275323879092 | Bitlocker Status | Off |
| COMPUTER2.companyA | 110275323879092 | SMART Drive Size | 455GB |
| COMPUTER2.companyA | 110275323879092 | SMART Updated | 01/14/2021 |
| COMPUTER2.companyA | 110275323879092 | SMART Status | CAUTION |

The table should end up looking like this:

| agentguid | Model | Size | Updated | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101159575290188 | PLEXTOR PX-256M5Pro ATA Device | 238GB | 01/14/2021 | CAUTION |
| 101159575290188 | ST500DM002-1BD142 | 455GB | 01/14/2021 | CAUTION |

I think my goal is to use either a PIVOT, UNPIVOT, or a CROSS, but I can't figure out how to make any of them work. Any help or guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thank you for the referred link, I read through it, and I still am not sure if it applies, especially because the right-most cell (fieldValue), is dependent on the cell to it's left (fieldName). In addition, the answers provided in that guide are all numbers being added together, while mine are strings that can't be merged. Each one of the 3000+ computers being queried will have a different result. Is PIVOT even the right tool? I'm just not sure what would be easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  agentguid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'SMART Drive Model' THEN fieldValue END)   AS Model,
  MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'SMART Drive Size'  THEN fieldValue END)   AS Size,
  MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'SMART Updated'     THEN fieldValue END)   AS Updated,
  MAX(CASE WHEN fieldName = 'SMART Status'      THEN fieldValue END)   AS Status
FROM
  vSystemInfoManual
GROUP BY
  agentguid
```

Comment: And of course, one should generally include an ORDER BY clause since order of rows almost always matters. Let's also not forget the statement terminator. Encourage good habits.